# STM BlueNRG maximum services

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32, bluenrg

I posted this question also in the STM Community Forum but you seldom really get help there

I'm struggling to get some detailed information on how to determine the correct number for the max_attr_records value of the aci_gatt_add_serv() function.

I know that you need 1 for the service itself and then at least 2 for each characteristic, but what else requires an attribute record?

Let say I have the following characteristic

```
aci_gatt_add_char(hServiceConfiguration, UUID_TYPE_128, uuid, 6,
                                   CHAR_PROP_NOTIFY|CHAR_PROP_READ|CHAR_PROP_WRITE, ATTR_PERMISSION_ENCRY_WRITE,
                                   GATT_NOTIFY_READ_REQ_AND_WAIT_FOR_APPL_RESP,
                                          16, 0 , &hCharTripConf);
```

What would be the resulting number of attribute records? I came up with 4, but I'm not sure if that's correct.

Further, there seems to be a limit for the total attribute records as I can only add a quite limited amount of services. How is this limit defined?